# Can the number of images in the swapchain change when it is recreated?

Tags: vulkan

While following the vulkan tutorial at https://vulkan-tutorial.com, I came across the line

> The descriptor pool should be destroyed when the swap chain is recreated because it depends on the number of images...

In the chapter on UBOs. Is it possible for the number of images in the swapchain to change when it is recreated?

Adding to my confusion, the tutorial uses a fence for each image, but the list of fences isn't recreated when the swapchain is recreated!

Comment: To clear up the confusion, the tutorial uses a fence for each frame, with the max frames in flight being set to 2. This value must be less than or equal to the number of images in the swap chain. This is why the fences do not need to be recreated when the swap chain is recreated.

Answer (score 1):

It is bit of a unresolved issue if the reported count can change: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/388

I think it does not happen in the wild under normal circumstances. Though being unresolved in the spec means some driver maker could claim it is valid. Probably best to program defensivively here.

One thing that is technically allowed to change is the count that `vkCreateSwapchain` creates:

> `minImageCount` is the minimum number of presentable images that the application needs. The implementation will either create the swapchain with **at least** that many images, or it will fail to create the swapchain.

Tutorial makers are only people too. I believe there's discussion at the end of each lesson where you can contact the author and ask him to clarify what he meant by his code.

Comment: Even if the surface capabilities min/max image count don't change, and you create the swapchain with the same `minImageCount` value, because of the part you quoted the number of images in the swapchain can still change. So the tutorial is right that *if* the descriptor pool is dependent on the swapchain size (which isn't how I'd do it, but isn't too unreasonable) then it should be recreated *if* the swapchain size is actually different.

Comment: @JesseHall My point was rather it is possible and encouraged to contact the authors directly. We do not need to speak about them in deference on 3rd party platforms. We are even talking about a **tutorial**. If something is not clear from it, then I'm sure the author would be happy to know what that is, so it can be improved.